# What is a Jetpack Compose @Composable function compiled to?

Tags: kotlin, compilation, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin1.4

I am exploring Android's new declarative UI framework, Jetpack Compose. After learning the basics, I am interested in how it's implemented, in which I am mostly interested in how a `@Composable` function is compiled. From some speech videos I learned that it requires a certain Kotlin language plugin/feature since 1.4 but they don't say what. I have also tried to use the "Show Kotlin Bytecode" feature in IntelliJ IDEA but there seem to be compilation errors.

So under the hood, what does this new Kotlin 1.4 language plugin/feature do and what definitions are generated from compiling one `@Composable` function?

Comment: This article explains how it works https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/under-the-hood-of-jetpack-compose-part-2-of-2-37b2c20c6cdd

As it mentions, it's quite similar to how suspending functions a Continuations work, that's also worth reading up on on its own if you're interested in the topic.

Comment: @zsmb13 Thanks I will have a look.